# Speed up replacement of very large alternatives expression

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement, code-request

I'm doing a computation which effectively has the same issue as this code:

```
Range@1000000 /. (Alternatives@@RandomSample[Range@1000000,500000]) -> 0
```

i.e. replacing each element of an arbitrary but large subset with a constant.  So, how can code like `list /. Alternatives@@subset->0` be made faster when `subset` is very large (close to half the size of `list`, so no benefit from inverting) and doesn't contain any exploitable patterns?

---

Perhaps the motivating problem is easier to solve: select those triangles in a mesh which cross an InfinitePlane, say InfinitePlane@{{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{0,0,1}}.  So, given a MeshRegion `m`,

```
fwd=First/@Position[MeshCoordinates@m,{_,_?Positive,_}]
back=First/@Position[MeshCoordinates@m,{_,_?NonPositive,_}]
Position[
  MeshCells[m,{2}]/.{Alternatives@@fwd->0,Alternatives@@back->1}
Polygon@{OrderlessPatternSequence[{1,0,_}]}]
```

I'm sure this could be made better, but I'm curious about the question it prompts about large `Alternative`s statements.

A way to do it better: don't 'cache' the results of `Positive`, and simply delete those polygons that are entirely on one side or the other:

```
Delete[MeshCells[m,{2}], 
  Position[MeshPrimitives[m,{2}], 
    Polygon[{{_,_?Positive,_},
             {_,_?Positive,_},
             {_,_?Positive, _}} |
            {{_,_?NonPositive,_},
             {_,_?NonPositive,_},
             {_,_?NonPositive,_}}
    ]
  ]
]
```

---

I can't figure out how to effectively use `Dispatch` or some clever numerical/floating point tricks to speed it up.

Comment: The performance characteristics of the replacement rule problem have changed in v13.3, see the new answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**: The `Thread` trick is not necessary any more in v13.3 to achieve full performance improvement; this trick is now effectively built-in behaviour. See [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287008/3056) below.

---

Use [threaded](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) rules instead of [alternatives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html): instead of `1 | 2 -> 0` use `{1 -> 0, 2 -> 0}`. Combined with a [`Dispatch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) or [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) this is very quick:

```
r = Thread[RandomSample[Range@1000000, 500000] -> 0];
Range@1000000 /. r; // AbsoluteTiming
(*    about two hours    *)

d = Dispatch[r]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.116651, Null}    *)
RepeatedTiming[Range@1000000 /. d;, 10]
(*    {0.392904, Null}    *)

a = Association[r]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {0.122811, Null}    *)
RepeatedTiming[Range@1000000 /. a;, 10]
(*    {0.379022, Null}    *)
```

So both `Dispatch` and `Association` are about 20000× faster than a simple rule replacement in this case. `Association` is even a little bit faster than `Dispatch`.

Thanks to @HenrikSchumacher for pointing out the use of `Association`. It is true that as of version 13.2.0 there is no longer any advantage of using `Dispatch`.

Comment: +1. One can also use an `Association` instead of a `Dispatch`. IIRC, this is a bit faster, making `Dispatch` quite obsolete nowadays...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It should be noted that `Association` works at this capacity only if your rules don't have patterns. `x /. <|_ -> foo|>` silently fails to perform the replacement. Maybe I should investigate if this should be considered a bug or a feature...

Comment: ... Yes, this is documented functionality. Hidden in the "possible issues" section of `Replace` documentation: "Associations can be used to specify replacement rules, but the keys are treated as Verbatim values."

Comment: Threaded behaviour of dispatch tables is implemented automatically starting with v13.3.

Answer (score 4):

`v2` is not as fast as Roman's `v1`

```
r = Range@100000;
s = RandomSample[r, 50000];

AbsoluteTiming[v1 = (
   d = Dispatch[Thread[s -> 0]];
   r /. d);]
```

> {0.104434, Null}

```
AbsoluteTiming[v2 = (
   Clear[test];
   Scan[(test[#] = True) &, s];
   test[_] = False;
   If[test[#], 0, #] & /@ r);]
```

> {0.268603, Null}

```
AbsoluteTiming[v3 = (r /. (Alternatives @@ s) -> 0);]
```

> {59.3356, Null}

```
v1 == v2 == v3
```

> True

Comment: You can gain a little bit of speed on your `v2` with `Clear[test]; SetAttributes[test, Listable]; Scan[(test[#] = 0) &, s]; test[x_] = x; test[r]` making use of the [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Dispatch` outlined in [the accepted answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277866/3056) is still highly beneficial in v13.3, but threading is not any more necessary since Mathematica now internally splits dispatch rules with alternatives on the left side to separate rules.

v13.2.1:

```
With[
 {dp = Dispatch[
    (Alternatives @@ RandomSample[Range@1000000, 500000]) -> 0]},
 Timing[Range@10000 /. dp;]]

(* {31.1677, Null} *)
```

vs. v13.3:

```
With[
 {dp = Dispatch[
    (Alternatives @@ RandomSample[Range@1000000, 500000]) -> 0]},
 Timing[Range@10000 /. dp;]]

(* {0.004174, Null} *)
```

A drawback of the new behaviour is that if the right-hand side of such a rule is large, the dispatch table may grow to a very large size. This can be worked around by first using a placeholder right hand side and replacing this placeholder with the large intended right hand side by applying a second replacement rule.

Comment: Always a tradeoff between expected use case and flexibility; this change seems to make `Dispatch` even *more* obsolete.  Regardless, excellent to have this info!

Comment: @Adam I wouldn't say so; I believe large alternatives form with a large right hand side is a very rare use case, but one with small right hand side is reasonably common (and remember, it supports patterns). There is room for improvement though; one could construct a separate table of alternatives right hand sides as a part of `Dispatch` object internal state and just store the index to that per split rule to manage memory usage, but I believe this code is in old C, and it isn't a low-hanging fruit, so to say. Also, an association form doesn't do better with large right hand sides...